# 'Cannot resolve keyword' error using generic relations

Tags: python, django

I am learning Django through a simple app that uses 2 objects - a user Profile object and a Groups object. A user can be part of multiple groups and a group can have multiple users.
I define a generic relation between both these objects.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    groups = generic.GenericRelation('Groups', null=True, blank=True, 
                     content_type_field='content_type', 
                     object_id_field='object_id', 
                     related_name='profile_groups')

    def deleteGroup(self, group_name):
        group_id = Groups.find_or_create(self, group_name, find_only=True)
        self.assertIsNotNone(group_id)
        group_id.delete()


class Groups(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    members = generic.GenericRelation(Profile, null=True, blank=True, 
                      related_name='group_members')
```

I get an error while deleting the group. I understand the error has something to do with passing args to filter() for GenericForeignKey or GenericRelation but earlier threads mention that in context with get_or_create() & not with delete()

Any help is much appreciated.

Error:

```
"models.py", in deleteGroup
    group_id.delete()
...
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 155, in   filter
    return self.get_query_set().filter(*args, **kwargs)
...
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword u'object_id' into field. Choices are: *<Profile objects global variable>*
```

Comment: What is `find_or_create`? A method you created?

Comment: This is similar to django's get_or_create method. It queries the DB for an entry, if found, returns the object otherwise returns None and creates the obj based on the 'find_only' flag.

Comment: Did you find any workaround ?